# UNPIVOT in Snowflake and adding additional columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to unpivot a table TABLE_A and add additional columns to the query

**TABLE_A:**

| YEAR | ID | OCT | NOV | DEC | JAN | FEB | MAR | APR | MAY | JUN | JUL | AUG | SEP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 1 | 10 | 5 | 5 | 10 | 5 | 10 | 15 | 20 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 10 |

Expected output:

| ID | MONTHLY_NO | MONTH | START_DATE | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 10 | 10-01-2021 | 2021 |
| 1 | 5 | 11 | 11-01-2021 | 2021 |
| 1 | 5 | 12 | 12-01-2021 | 2021 |
| 1 | 10 | 1 | 01-01-2022 | 2022 |
| 1 | 5 | 2 | 02-01-2022 | 2022 |
| 1 | 10 | 3 | 03-01-2022 | 2022 |
| 1 | 15 | 4 | 04-01-2022 | 2022 |
| 1 | 20 | 5 | 05-01-2022 | 2022 |
| 1 | 5 | 6 | 06-01-2022 | 2022 |
| 1 | 0 | 7 | 07-01-2022 | 2022 |
| 1 | 0 | 8 | 08-01-2022 | 2022 |
| 1 | 10 | 9 | 09-01-2022 | 2022 |

Query that I used:

```
SELECT ID, 
MONTHLY_NO, 
CASE 
WHEN TGT_MONTH='JAN' THEN 1
WHEN TGT_MONTH='FEB' THEN 2
WHEN TGT_MONTH='MAR' THEN 3
WHEN TGT_MONTH='APR' THEN 4
WHEN TGT_MONTH='MAY' THEN 5
WHEN TGT_MONTH='JUN' THEN 6
WHEN TGT_MONTH='JUL' THEN 7
WHEN TGT_MONTH='AUG' THEN 8
WHEN TGT_MONTH='SEP' THEN 9
WHEN TGT_MONTH='OCT' THEN 10
WHEN TGT_MONTH='NOV' THEN 11
WHEN TGT_MONTH='DEC' THEN 12
END AS MONTH
FROM TABLE_A
UNPIVOT( MONTHLY_NO FOR TGT_MONTH IN (JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC));
```

How can I add START_DATE and YEAR columns to the query? Could you please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the pattern in the [UNPIVOT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/unpivot.html) doc's, with your `table_a`

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a
UNPIVOT( monthly_no FOR tgt_month IN (jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec))
```

should give (ignoring lack of ordering, and assuming `year`, `id`, and `monthly_no` are both NUMBER's):

```
YEAR    ID  TGT_MONTH   MONTHLY_NO
2022    1   'JAN'       10
2022    1   'FEB'       5
2022    1   'MAR'       10
2022    1   'APR'       15
2022    1   'MAY'       20
2022    1   'JUN'       5
2022    1   'JUL'       0
2022    1   'AUG'       0
2022    1   'AUG'       10
2022    1   'OCT'       10
2022    1   'NOV'       5
2022    1   'DEC'       5
```

if you are not bothered by column order to can use a single inline form:

```
SELECT year, 
    id, 
    monthly_no, 
    TO_DATE(year::text || tgt_month, 'YYYYMON') AS start_date, 
    MONTH(start_date) AS month
FROM table_a
UNPIVOT( monthly_no FOR tgt_month IN (jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec))
```

otherwise to get it in the order you want you have to do the same logic repeatedly, or nest it.

repaeted version:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    monthly_no, 
    MONTH(TO_DATE(year::text || tgt_month, 'YYYYMON')) AS month,
    TO_DATE(year::text || tgt_month, 'YYYYMON') AS start_date,
    year    
FROM table_a
UNPIVOT( monthly_no FOR tgt_month IN (jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec))
```

nested:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    monthly_no, 
    MONTH(start_date) AS month,
    start_date,
    year    
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        monthly_no, 
        TO_DATE(year::text || tgt_month, 'YYYYMON') AS start_date,
        year    
    FROM table_a
    UNPIVOT( monthly_no FOR tgt_month IN (jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec))
)
```

Oh, I have just grok'ed you Oct, Nov, Dec are 2021 on purpose, even though you don't mention it.. This can be fixed with some inline IFF

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    monthly_no, 
    MONTH(start_date) AS month,
    IFF(month >= 10, DATEADD('year', -1, start_date), start_date) AS start_date
    IFF(month >= 10, year -1, year) AS year 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        monthly_no, 
        TO_DATE(year::text || tgt_month, 'YYYYMON') AS start_date,
        year    
    FROM table_a
    UNPIVOT( monthly_no FOR tgt_month IN (jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec))
)
```

Comment: Thank you, Simeon ! Your answer is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able just to select the additional columns you need. I used a SQL server example for this, but in principle it should work the same way. See my query below:

```
SELECT ID, 
year,
CASE
WHEN TGT_MONTH='JAN' THEN '01/01/'+CAST(year as CHAR(4))
WHEN TGT_MONTH='FEB' THEN '02/01/'+CAST(year as CHAR(4))
WHEN TGT_MONTH='MAR' THEN '03/01/'+CAST(year as CHAR(4))
WHEN TGT_MONTH='APR' THEN '04/01/'+CAST(year as CHAR(4))
WHEN TGT_MONTH='MAY' THEN '05/01/'+CAST(year as CHAR(4))
WHEN TGT_MONTH='JUN' THEN '06/01/'+CAST(year as CHAR(4))
WHEN TGT_MONTH='JUL' THEN '07/01/'+CAST(year as CHAR(4))
WHEN TGT_MONTH='AUG' THEN '08/01/'+CAST(year as CHAR(4))
WHEN TGT_MONTH='SEP' THEN '09/01/'+CAST(year as CHAR(4))
WHEN TGT_MONTH='OCT' THEN '10/01/'+CAST(year as CHAR(4))
WHEN TGT_MONTH='NOV' THEN '11/01/'+CAST(year as CHAR(4))
WHEN TGT_MONTH='DEC' THEN '12/01/'+CAST(year as CHAR(4))
END as starting_date,
CASE 
WHEN TGT_MONTH='JAN' THEN 1
WHEN TGT_MONTH='FEB' THEN 2
WHEN TGT_MONTH='MAR' THEN 3
WHEN TGT_MONTH='APR' THEN 4
WHEN TGT_MONTH='MAY' THEN 5
WHEN TGT_MONTH='JUN' THEN 6
WHEN TGT_MONTH='JUL' THEN 7
WHEN TGT_MONTH='AUG' THEN 8
WHEN TGT_MONTH='SEP' THEN 9
WHEN TGT_MONTH='OCT' THEN 10
WHEN TGT_MONTH='NOV' THEN 11
WHEN TGT_MONTH='DEC' THEN 12
END AS MONTH
FROM 
  (
     SELECT year, id, oct, nov, dec, jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep
     FROM monthly_sales
  ) as pvt
  UNPIVOT(MONTHLY_NO FOR TGT_MONTH IN (JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC))
  As unpvt;
```

You can see my sqlfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/48ee0/7/0

Comment: Thank you ! If you notice the years and months from october to december, it would be current year -1. With your approach, I would need another case statement to handle FY i take?